# Extract a substring from a variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I want to remove a specific substring from a variable in Ansible and store the result into another variable. Say I have something like below:

`greeting: "Hello_World"`

I want to remove the substring *"_World"* from *greeting* and store the result in another Ansible variable.

**Example:**
`greet_word: "Hello"`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please edit your question with what you already tried and the exact problem you have to reach your target.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Q: **"*Remove the substring '_World'*"**

A: There are more options:

- Use the filter [*regex_replace*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions)

```yaml
  greet_word: "{{ greeting|regex_replace('^(.*)_World(.*)$', '\\1\\2') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  greet_word: Hello
```

- Split the string on the underscore '_' and take the first item.  The expressions below give the same result.

```yaml
  greet_word: "{{ greeting.split('_').0 }}
```

```yaml
  greet_word: "{{ greeting.split('_')|first }}
```

- Use the Jinja filter [*replace*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.replace). The expression below gives the same result.

```yaml
  greet_word: "{{ greeting|replace('_World', '') }}"
```

Comment: to understand Regular expressions watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sa-TUpSx1JA

Answer (score 0):

You can try [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) module and [regular expressions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html)

```
    - name: Extract substring from a variable
      set_fact:
        new_variable: "{{ variable | regex_search() }}"
```

Can test regular expressions with any online service, also can check what you are getting with [debug](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/debug_module.html)